# Javascript div .hide function

Tags: javascript, html

I have a text input with an id of `auto_change_date` and i am trying to hide it on page load using:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#auto_change_date").hide();
});
```

but its just not hiding it

i am then using this code to make it display (.show) when a select option is selected:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#status').on('change',function(){
    if( $(this).val()==="Auto Change"){
    $("#auto_change_date").show()
    }
    else{
    $("#auto_change_date").hide()
    }
});
</script>
```

Comment: What error do you get in the browser console?

Comment: no error, the text input just still displays

Comment: can you make a fiddle.net ???

Comment: Ok, can you show the HMTL you're applying it to?

Comment: have you include the jquery library?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/xTHt5/

Comment: @SatishSharma yeah i have

Comment: How about this `<input type="text" id="auto_change_date" style="display:none;" >` or `<input type="hidden" id="auto_change_date">` ?

Comment: @charlie you have not included the library in fiddle

Comment: @charlie and you are using tag name instead of your id put id attibute in your input field

Comment: yep - your right, can u make that an answer please :)

Comment: @charlie check my answer and fiddle and reply

Comment: @charlie, You should always bind events in document-ready handler function. thus bind this event also `$('#status').on('change',function(){`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<input type="text" name="auto_change_date" onclick="ds_sh(this);" />
```

you are missing here id

put it as follows

```
<input type="text" name="auto_change_date"  id="auto_change_date" onclick="ds_sh(this);" />
```

now your jquery will work fine

See [**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/xTHt5/2/)

Answer (score 1):

Nothing is wrong with Your jQuery. But I would suggest you to use Pure CSS

```
<style>
    #auto_change_date {
        display:none;
    }
</style>
```

OR, Simple JavaScript

```
  document.getElementById('auto_change_date').style.display = 'none';
```

Comment: yep. i agree with satpal. i don´t think for what you want its necessary to use javascript... pure css is the best way

Answer (score 1):

Add html input type = "text" with id = "auto_change_date"

```
<input type="text" id="auto_change_date" />
```

Now add following javascript function:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#auto_change_date").hide();
});
```

Its Working fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

With vanilla Javascript

```
var input = document.getElementById('auto_change_date');
input.style.display = 'none';
```

or

```
input.style.visibility = 'hidden';
```

Answer (score 0):

simply try something like this

```
    <input type="text"  id="auto_change_date" name="auto_change_date" onclick="ds_sh(this);" />
```

your javascript code should be like this

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#status').on('change',function(){
            if(this).value ==="Auto Change" ){
                $("#auto_change_date").show();
            } else {
                $("#auto_change_date").hide();
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 <style>
    .hidden{
        display:none;
    }
</style>


<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#auto_change_date').addClass('hidden');
$("#auto_change_date").hide();
});
</script>
```

the div should be made `display:none` at first inorder to apply this

Answer (score 0):

You are not defining id to element and you should add jquery js to work this.

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
```

Html :

```
<input type="text" id="auto_change_date" name="auto_change_date" onclick="ds_sh(this);" />
```

Comment: If you want this using element.hide() Check fiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/xTHt5/4/)